# Google Spreadsheets DAVERAGE database function criteria syntax: substring match?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can I for [DAVERAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094144?hl=en) write a restriction in a filter so that the filter matches a database row if the restriction text matches either exactly or as a substring? Example: restriction `b` for column X by default matches rows with `b` in column X but not rows with `cab`. Can I wildcard/prefix/etc the restriction `b` to match also `cab`?

(Set aside the option to make one filter row for `b`, one for `cab`, ... since tedius when there are many different target strings with b in them.)

Google's [Database functions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/173497) helppage says:

> The first row in Criteria specifies field names. Every other row in Criteria represents a filter, which is a set of restrictions on the corresponding fields. Restrictions are described using Query-by-Example notation, and can include a value to match or a comparison operator followed by a comparison value. Examples of restrictions are: "Chocolate", "42", ">= 42", "<> 42". An empty cell means no restriction on the corresponding field.
>   A filter matches a database row if all the filter restrictions (the restrictions in the filter's row) are met. A database row (record) satisfies Criteria if and only if at least one filter matches it. A field name may appear more than once in the Criteria range to allow multiple restrictions that apply simultaneously (for example, temperature >= 65 and temperature <= 82)."

Google's [example spreadsheet](http://docs.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0As3tAuweYU9QdEVHdTFHNzloSTY4LVYxdW9LdHRHbEE&mode=public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use wild cards with the Dfunctions. So you might use something like this as your criteria:

`"*b*"`

Comment: Thanks, works. Simple is good. Could swear I tried that before posting but apparently had some other error earlier.